# How to do this specific list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
points = [
    [[x,y], [x,y], [x,y]],
    [[x,y], [x,y], [x,y], [x,y], [x,y]],
    [[x,y]]
]

weights = [1, 2, 3]

output  = [
    [[x,y,1], [x,y,1], [x,y,1]],
    [[x,y,2], [x,y,2], [x,y,2], [x,y,2], [x,y,2]],   
    [[x,y,3]]
]
```

I want to combine Points and Weights to ultimately look like the output column. The length of points and weights will always be the same. However, the amount of [x,y] pairs will differ for each list inside the list. Exactly how I have shown the example. Python is the language I am using.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How would you do it for a single case? e.g. given `[[x,y], [x,y], [x,y]]` and `1`, how would you produce the output `[[x,y,1], [x,y,1], [x,y,1]]`?

Comment: To do the simple single case that @Alexander-ReinstateMonica suggests, you can do `[pt.append(1) for pt in points]` which adds 1 at the end of `points` in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work from the inside out.

On the inside, we have `[[x, y], [x, y], [x, y]]` and `1`, and we want to produce `[[x, y, 1], [x, y, 1], [x, y, 1]]`.

So, we are appending `1` to each of the `[x, y]` values. But `.append` modifies a value *in-place* and returns `None`; to do work with list-comprehensions, we want to return new values. So we can instead create `[1]` from the input `1`, and concatenate lists with `+`.

Therefore, we want the given inner `item`, `+` an appended list `[1]`, `for` each of the `item`s that is found `in` our original data (`[[x, y], [x, y], [x, y]]`). Since we are going to apply this to nested lists, let's say that we refer to that list as a `row`. Then, we write the list comprehension, describing that task - exactly as I put it, reading left to right: `[item + [1] for item in row]`.

(Edit: as noted in the other answer, it also works to take advantage of unpacking: instead of `item + [1]`, we can do `[*item, 1]`.)

Now: that is the sort of processing that we want to do to each `row`. But we want to use a different value instead of the `1` each time. Those values come from `weights`, which we want to iterate in parallel with the `row`s of the overall `points`.

So, we need to use `zip` in order to pair up each `weight` of the `weights` with a corresponding `row` from `points`. That looks like `zip(points, weights)`, and when we iterate over that, we get `(row, weight)` pairs.

Our processing for a given `row` now looks like `[item + [weight] for item in row]`, after modifying it to account for the varying `weight`.

So we apply the technique again: we want to do `[item + [weight] for item in row]`, `for` each of the `(row, weight)` pairs (parentheses are not strictly necessary here, but make things a lot easier to understand) that are found `in` our `zip`ped lists of `points` and `weights`. And again, we read that left to right:

```
[[item + [weight] for item in row] for (row, weight) in zip(points, weights)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `zip` it's relatively easy:

```
[[p+[w] for p in pl] for pl, w in zip(points, weights)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-liner list comprehension without using a zip -

```
[[k+[weights[i]] for k in j] for i,j in enumerate(points)]
```